# How to use LifecycleScope/Coroutine instead of handler in Audio Player code Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, audio-player

I was trying a youtube tutorial on how to create a simple Audio Player in Kotlin. While working on it, I found that constructor Handler() is deprecated. I did some google searches for a solution and it appeared that LifecycleScope/Coroutine can be used instead. Any idea how can I change following code with the new LifecycleScope/Coroutine?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
private var mp: MediaPlayer? = null
private var currentSong = mutableListOf(R.raw.high_sky)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    controlSound(currentSong[0])
}

private fun controlSound(id: Int) {
    binding.fabPlay.setOnClickListener{

        if(mp == null){
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,id)
            Log .d("Mainactivity", "ID: ${mp!!.audioSessionId}")

            initialiseSeekbar()
        }
            mp?.start()
        Log .d("Mainactivity", "Duration: ${mp!!.duration/1000} seconds")

    }

    binding.fabPause.setOnClickListener{
        if (mp !== null) mp?.pause()
        Log .d("Mainactivity", "Paused at: ${mp!!.currentPosition/1000} seconds")

    }

    binding.fabStop.setOnClickListener{
        if (mp!==null) {
            mp?.stop()
            mp?.reset()
            mp?.release()
            mp = null
        }
    }

    binding.seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{
        override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
            if (fromUser) mp?.seekTo(progress)
        }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
        }

        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
        }

    })

}
private fun initialiseSeekbar(){
    binding.seekbar.max = mp!!.duration

    val handler = Handler()
    handler.postDelayed(object: Runnable {
        override fun run(){
            try{
                binding.seekbar.progress = mp!!.currentPosition
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                binding.seekbar.progress =0
            }
        }

    }, 0)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can still use `Handler`: it's just the no-argument constructor that is deprecated. They would just like you to specify a `Looper`:

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
```

That will work without a warning.